# How is possible to connect 3x 100w led lights to a 300w led driver?

Tags: power-supply, led, driver

Could you explain if is possible to connect 3x lamps of 100w to 300w led driver?

The led driver specification is: constant current, 27-36v, 9A.

The lights:
1x, 27-30v, 3.5A, and
2x, 30-36, 3A.

So, can I connect lamps with differents voltages to this driver?

If not, is it possible if the voltage of these lamps are the same?

What can I do in this situation? what you sugest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

LED voltage varies between individual units and with temperature. The current is what really matters and needs to be controlled. While you could try to balance currents in a parallel arrangement, it's prone to problems that will potentially fry your LEDs, even if they all claim to be the same voltage.

In general, driving LEDs in series so the current can be precisely controlled is preferable to mucking about with parallel arrangements, if the intent is to drive them efficiently. If you are happy burning a lot of power (heat) in resistors you can parallel things more reliably, but in this case you have not got much voltage headroom or enough current to do so. You *might* manage to drive two of the 27-30V 3.5A variety off this supply, with 2 ohm resistors in series with each one.

So, the fact that the lights are described as 100W each and the power supply is described as 300W does not mean you can expect to hook the power supply up to 3 lamps, in this case. I suggest buying additional power supplies as being most likely to solve your problem reliably and without killing your LED lamps.